# Is there a way to make sure the hovered over element is then moved to be front and center?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have this project where I was asked to recreate [this object](https://webkit.org/blog-files/3d-transforms/morphing-cubes.html). Making it is no issue. The problem is, they also want it to stop when the user hovers over it. Now, this also isn't an issue, as :hover is pretty standard in CSS. The problem is, that when the user hovers over it, the face that stops is stopped exactly where it is.

What I want to know is if there is a way to make the face (or plane, in the case of the code) finish up the distance it needs to go to return to the center of the screen. So for example, say the user is in the ring mode (after clicking toggle shape on the site) and they hover over the number 3. What I want it to do is, if the face is to the left of the center, slowly move back to the right and then stop when it's in the center and vice-versa for if it's to the right. I'm somewhat new to CSS animations so I have no idea how to make this work.

Here is my code that I have so far:

```css
 
  body {
    background-color: black;
    /* font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial; */
    font-size: 12px;
    /* background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial,
                          50% 500, 1,
                          50% 500, 400,
                          from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)),
                          to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
   background-repeat: no-repeat; */
  }

  #stage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  #shape {
    position: relative;
    top: 160px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }
  
  .plane {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-family: Times, serif;
    font-size: 350%;
    color: black;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, opacity 2s;
  }
  

  #shape.backfaces .plane {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
  }
  
  #shape {
    -webkit-animation: spin 8s infinite linear;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
    to   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
  }


  .cube > .one {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .two {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .three {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .four {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .five {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .six {
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px) rotate(180deg);
  }


  .cube > .seven {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px) rotate(180deg);
  }

  .cube > .eight {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .nine {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .ten {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .eleven {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  .cube > .twelve {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
  }

  /* ---------- ring styles ------------- */
  .ring > .one {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .two {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .three {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .four {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .five {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .six {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .seven {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .eight {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .nine {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-120deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .ten {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .eleven {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(380px);
  }

  .ring > .twelve {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(380px);
  }


  #shape:hover  {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  }

  /* #shape.backfaces:hover .plane {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px,0,175px);
    -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    z-index: 2;
  } */
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<div id="stage">
    <div onclick="toggleShape()" id="shape" class="cube backfaces">
      <div id="1" onmouseover="ringHoverOver(this)" class="plane one">$3M</div>
      <div id="2" class="plane two">$175K</div>
      <div id="3" class="plane three">2K</div>
      <div id="4" class="plane four">Thousands</div>
      <div id="5" class="plane five">30</div>
      <div id="6" class="plane six">20+</div>
      <div id="7" class="plane seven">25</div>
      <div id="8" class="plane eight">Hundreds</div>
      <div id="9" class="plane nine">Tens of Thousands</div>
      <div id="10" class="plane ten">Dozens</div>
      <div id="11" class="plane eleven">15+</div>
      <div id="12" class="plane twelve">All </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    const startingInfo = {}
    const shape = document.getElementById('shape');
    function hasClassName(inElement, inClassName)
    {
        var regExp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s+)' + inClassName + '(?:\\s+|$)');
        return regExp.test(inElement.className);
    }

    function addClassName(inElement, inClassName)
    {
        if (!hasClassName(inElement, inClassName))
            inElement.className = [inElement.className, inClassName].join(' ');
    }

    function removeClassName(inElement, inClassName)
    {
        if (hasClassName(inElement, inClassName)) {
            var regExp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s+)' + inClassName + '(?:\\s+|$)', 'g');
            var curClasses = inElement.className;
            inElement.className = curClasses.replace(regExp, ' ');
        }
    }
    
    function toggleShape()
    {
      if (hasClassName(shape, 'cube')) {
        removeClassName(shape, 'cube');
        addClassName(shape, 'ring');
        const planes = document.querySelectorAll(".plane")
        for (const plane of planes){
            startingInfo[plane.id] = [plane.getBoundingClientRect()['x'], plane.getBoundingClientRect()['y']]
        }
      } 
      // Move the ring back in Z so it's not so in-your-face.
      var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
      if (hasClassName(shape, 'ring'))
        stage.style.webkitTransform = 'translateZ(-200px)';
      else
        stage.style.webkitTransform = '';
    }

    // const ringHoverOver = (e) => {
    //     shape.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0,0,0)"
    // }

  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Morphing Power Cubes</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Lucida Grande', Verdana, Arial;
      font-size: 12px;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(radial,
                            50% 500, 1,
                            50% 500, 400,
                            from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)),
                            to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
      -webkit-perspective: 800; /* For compatibility with iPhone 3.0, we leave off the units here */
      -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 225px;
    }
    #stage {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    
    #shape {
      position: relative;
      top: 160px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }
    
    .plane {
      position: absolute;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      border: 1px solid white;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Times, serif;
      font-size: 124pt;
      color: black;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
      -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s, opacity 2s;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    #shape.backfaces .plane {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    }
    
    #shape {
      -webkit-animation: spin 8s infinite linear;
    }
    #shape:hover {
    -webkit-animation: spinhover 8s linear forwards;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
      from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
      to   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes spinhover {
      from { -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg); }
      to   { -webkit-transform: rotateY(0); }
    }

    /* ---------- cube styles ------------- */
    .cube > .one {
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .two {
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .three {
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .four {
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .five {
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .six {
      opacity: 0.5;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px) rotate(180deg);
    }


    .cube > .seven {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateX(90deg) translateZ(100px) rotate(180deg);
    }

    .cube > .eight {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .nine {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateY(90deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .ten {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .eleven {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    .cube > .twelve {
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8) rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px);
    }

    /* ---------- ring styles ------------- */
    .ring > .one {
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .two {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .three {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .four {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .five {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .six {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(150deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .seven {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .eight {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(210deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .nine {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-120deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .ten {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .eleven {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(300deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .ring > .twelve {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(330deg) translateZ(380px);
    }

    .controls {
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    }
    .controls > div {
      margin: 10px;
    }
    
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function hasClassName(inElement, inClassName)
    {
        var regExp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s+)' + inClassName + '(?:\\s+|$)');
        return regExp.test(inElement.className);
    }

    function addClassName(inElement, inClassName)
    {
        if (!hasClassName(inElement, inClassName))
            inElement.className = [inElement.className, inClassName].join(' ');
    }

    function removeClassName(inElement, inClassName)
    {
        if (hasClassName(inElement, inClassName)) {
            var regExp = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s+)' + inClassName + '(?:\\s+|$)', 'g');
            var curClasses = inElement.className;
            inElement.className = curClasses.replace(regExp, ' ');
        }
    }

    function toggleClassName(inElement, inClassName)
    {
        if (hasClassName(inElement, inClassName))
            removeClassName(inElement, inClassName);
        else
            addClassName(inElement, inClassName);
    }

    function toggleShape()
    {
      var shape = document.getElementById('shape');
      if (hasClassName(shape, 'ring')) {
        removeClassName(shape, 'ring');
        addClassName(shape, 'cube');
      } else {
        removeClassName(shape, 'cube');
        addClassName(shape, 'ring');
      }
      
      // Move the ring back in Z so it's not so in-your-face.
      var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
      if (hasClassName(shape, 'ring'))
        stage.style.webkitTransform = 'translateZ(-200px)';
      else
        stage.style.webkitTransform = '';
    }
    
    function toggleBackfaces()
    {
      var backfacesVisible = document.getElementById('backfaces').checked;
      var shape = document.getElementById('shape');
      if (backfacesVisible)
        addClassName(shape, 'backfaces');
      else
        removeClassName(shape, 'backfaces');
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="controls">
    <h1>Animations, Transitions and 3D Transforms</h1>
    <p>This demo shows some more interesting content using 3D transforms, animations and transitions.
      Note that you can still select the text on the the elements, even while they are rotating. Transforms elements remain
        fully interactive.</p>
    <p>Click Toggle Shape to switch between nested cubes and one big ring. Note how the planes move smoothly to their new locations,
      even while the whole shape is rotating. You can even interrupt this transition by clicking again, and they move back smoothly.</p>
    <p>Toggle the Backfaces Visible checkbox to turn backfaces on and off using <code>-webkit-backface-visibility</code>.</p>
    <div><button onclick="toggleShape()">Toggle Shape</button></div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="backfaces" onclick="toggleBackfaces()" checked><label for="backfaces">Backfaces visible</label></div>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="stage">
      <div id="shape" class="cube backfaces">
        <div class="plane one">1</div>
        <div class="plane two">2</div>
        <div class="plane three">3</div>
        <div class="plane four">4</div>
        <div class="plane five">5</div>
        <div class="plane six">6</div>
        <div class="plane seven">7</div>
        <div class="plane eight">8</div>
        <div class="plane nine">9</div>
        <div class="plane ten">10</div>
        <div class="plane eleven">11</div>
        <div class="plane twelve">12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, when answering with a piece of code. [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: This doesn't work. It just makes it spin in the opposite direction on hover. I was trying to see if there is a way to make it so that it only moves back in the other direction enough distance so that the face hovered over is dead center.